# Display Register box if user does't have an account, Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to display the registration option if the user doesn't have an account and show the box in the same pagem like this;

[Check the result I want](http://prntscr.com/hvx4on)

From the option: ¿No tiene una cuenta? Cree una. Clicking the tex, the box is displayed and the user can create an account on the system. The thing is that I don't know how to make this happen, to add the effect.

```
<?php
       echo "<br>";
    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        exit; // Exit if accessed directly
    }

    ?>

    <?php wc_print_notices(); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' ); ?>

    <?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) === 'no' ) : ?>

    <div class="u-columns col2-set" id="customer_login">

        <div class="u-column1 col-1">

    <?php endif; ?>

            <h2><?php _e( 'Login', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

            <form class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-login login" method="post">

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_start' ); ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="username"><?php _e( 'Username or email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( $_POST['username'] ) : ''; ?>" />
                </p>
                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="password"><?php _e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" type="password" name="password" id="password" />
                </p>

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form' ); ?>

                <p class="form-row">
                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-login', 'woocommerce-login-nonce' ); ?>
                    <input type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="login" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Login', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
                    <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox inline">
                        <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> <span><?php _e( 'Remember me', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
                    </label>
                </p>
                <p class="woocommerce-LostPassword lost_password"> <!--HERE I WANT TO CHANGE THE get_option TO 'no' and display the box-->                   <!-- <a href="<?php echo (get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) === 'no'); ?>"><?php _e( '¿No tiene una cuenta? Cree una. <br>', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a> -->

                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url() ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Lost your password?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
                </p>

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_end' ); ?>
            </form>
    <?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) === 'yes' ) : ?>

        </div>

        <div class="u-column2 col-2">

            <h2><?php _e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

            <form method="post" class="register">

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>
                <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>

                    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                        <label for="reg_username"><?php _e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( $_POST['username'] ) : ''; ?>" />
                    </p>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_email"><?php _e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ) : ''; ?>" />
                </p>

                <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>

                    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                        <label for="reg_password"><?php _e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" />
                    </p>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>
                <p class="woocommerce-FormRow form-row">
                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
                    <input type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
                </p>

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_customer_login_form' ); ?>
```

I don't know how to make the:

```
<?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) === 'yes' ) : ?>
```

make it change to 'no' from the text I have mentioned, just if I let all of those in 'no' the result is like in the pic I have put, but I want to make it dynamic.

I hope I have explained well.

Thank you in advance,

inhaki

Comment: Plenty of plugins will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can force guest users to register before checkout by disabling an option in the WC Admin:

WooCommerce > Settings > Checkout > Allow checkout as guest

I'm not sure about the actual checkbox text since my WP installation is in Spanish, but it's something like that. I don't know if that's what you're looking for. If it isn't, elaborate a little bit more on why do you wanna tap into the WC code to solve this. Maybe you're looking for something more specific.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my WP also is in Spanish! And about why I want to tap the WC code is because I wanna make the option appear dynamically, when the user clicks the "¿No tiene una cuenta? Cree una.", the Register dialog should appear, but not from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

update_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration', 'yes' );